# Build new container with data from a list by click on a button in Flutter

Tags: list, flutter, flutter-layout

In Flutter I have a container which contains current time and some text from `List(datatype)`.

When ever I click a button it should fetch the items inside the list and put them on container and the container should be build.

When I press the button again It should do the same thing below with the next Entry.

Comment: could you share some code and an picture or example of what you expect?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to take a list of the type widget and fill it within a SetState to rebuild the state, you can build this list with a ListView.builder

```
List data = ["data1", "data2", "data3"]; // The data you get from the API
int  _i = 0; //the amount of containers you want.
```

#### The builder

```
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: i,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index) {
    return new Container(child: Text(data.index.toString());
     }
)
```

#### The button to increment:

```
onPressed: (){
   setState(() { //setState for rebuilding the page.
       _i++;
     });
},
```